# How to fix "Not enough memory" on Windows 7 and PHP 7.2.0 (cli)

Tags: wp-cli

I installed **wp-cli** tool on windows 7 but when I type **wp --help**. It noticed error "**Out of memory**". Pleased help me know WHY and how to fix it?

Comment: Check your php.ini (for cli) for `memory_limit` - make sure it's sufficiently high. If you don't know where it is, run `phpinfo()` and look at the php.ini paths that are printed.

Comment: Default `memory_limit=128M`. I changed `memory_limit=512M` in file **php.ini** but it was not working. @janh